# 'JSON' is undefined' issue in IE but not chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I am getting the following error with my jquery ajax call in IE9, where I am using Json.stringify().

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

The same function was working for me till yesterday and still works on my colleagues machine and on chrome on my machine. But for no apparent reason has stopped working on my machine today.

May you please help me understand, what is causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: No. I don't think so. How to check?

Comment: IE9’s Document Modes and JavaScript: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/24/ie9-s-document-modes-and-javascript.aspx  You can figure out what mode you're in by hitting F12 and looking at the upper-right.

Comment: Changing the Document Mode solved it for me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have your document is rendered in standards mode.
See this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/fc41127c-0243-4d2e-8e7c-2b311f12e390.

Answer (score 11):

the solution for me was to turn OFF compatibility mode by clicking the "torn page" icon to the right of the address bar.

Who knows how it got turned on in the first place!

Comment: IE11, "Compatibility view settings", enabled seems to be default for Intranet sites - presumably the presumption is that most intranet sites are most likely microsoft packages and therefore not compatible with their own browser.